# Equation numbering not shown

Tags: equations, labels

I am writing an equation using the syntax s follows:-

```
{
\[
  N\!D_{\max} = 
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2} &:  \text{$n$   even,} \\ 
    \frac{n-1}{2} &: \text{$n$  odd.}
   \end{cases}
\]  }\label{form:19}
```

I am able to label the equation during a sentence but the same equation number is not being shown beside the equation. How can I fix this problem? A picture

[image]

is attached for better understanding.

Comment: As always on the this site: please post a full minimal example instead of sniplet. `\[... \] ` dies not number equations so I don't know what you are expecting with that label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `equation` environment to get equation numbers or you can use `\tag` statement to give whatever equation number that you want to give.

[image]

```
{
\[
  N\!D_{\max} = 
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2} &:  \text{$n$   even,} \\ 
    \frac{n-1}{2} &: \text{$n$  odd.}
   \end{cases}
\]  }\label{form:19}

Referring to Equation~\ref{form:19}.


{
\[
  N\!D_{\max} = 
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2} &:  \text{$n$   even,} \\ 
    \frac{n-1}{2} &: \text{$n$  odd.}
   \end{cases}\tag{3.2}\label{form:19a}
\]  }

Referring to Equation~\ref{form:19a}.


\begin{equation}
  N\!D_{\max} = 
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2} &:  \text{$n$   even,} \\ 
    \frac{n-1}{2} &: \text{$n$  odd.}
   \end{cases}
   \label{form:19b}
\end{equation}

Referring to Equation~\ref{form:19b}.
```

Answer (score 4):

The braces around the equation are wrong; also, if you want a numbered equation you need `equation`, not `\[...\]`. The `\label` should go inside it.

Here's a corrected version, using some more facilities from `mathtools`, for instance `dcases*` (see its manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\ND}{\mathit{ND}}

\begin{document}

The nodal diameter ($\ND$) of a deformation or excitation shape
is equal to the number of ``inflection lines'' across the disk.
The maximum nodal diameter $\ND_{\max}$ is given by Eq.~\eqref{form:19}
where $n$ denotes the number of periodic sections
\begin{equation}\label{form:19}
\ND_{\max}=
\begin{dcases*}
\frac{n}{2}   & $n$ even, \\
\frac{n-1}{2} & $n$ odd.
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]